# GitKraken changes do not show -- disconnected from repo

Tags: git, windows-10, gitkraken

GitKraken changes are not visible to the rest of the applications accessing the same repository.

Example: when I double click on a remote branch, the checkout mark correctly appears on the UI next to the branch-name. However, when I run `git branch` on *cmd* I am still on the previously checked-out branch.

No changes performed on GitKraken appear on either

- windows command prompt (cmd)
- visual studio code terminal
- Cmder terminal

Re-installing the applications made no difference. Neither running them as administrator.

I am using *GitKraken 4.2.1*, *vscode 1.30.2* and *Cmder 1.3.11* on *windows 10 Enterprise* and my code is hosted on *TFS*.

Comment: Are there any changes that _do_ show in the command line after making them in Git Kraken?  If you make changes on the command line do you see them in Git Kraken?

Comment: Changes only appear in the terminal. GitKraken just refuses to see any changes done in my project (no unstaged files on the branch). The problem persists even when I checkout on the same branch as gitKraken on the terminal. It feels as if gitKraken is not connected with the local repo.

Comment: To explain a little better: 

git checkout <my_branch> works in terminal but gitKraken does not switch branches and vice-versa.

Also file changes appear in the terminal but does not show on gitKraken.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot maybe of Git Kraken?  I _also_ feel like Git Kraken is not connected to the local repo.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. I will post my steps in case this happens to someone else as well. This behaviour was very strange and I have no clue what triggered the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I managed to resolve the issue.

GitKraken was actually connected to the local repo but only **partially**. I was able to correctly fetch and pull from origin but any local changes did not reflect in GitKraken's UI.

My solution:

1. uninstall GitKraken
2. delete GitKraken folder from `AppData/Local`
3. delete GitKraken folder from `AppData/Roaming`
4. delete `.gitkraken` folder from `AppData/Roaming`
5. Re-install GitKraken version 4.1.1 (not latest)
6. Open local repository [At this point the issue was resolved.]
7. Upgrade to version 4.2.1 which now works as intended.

Subnote: 
I also deleted GitKraken from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\GitKraken` registry but I do not believe this was relevant at all.